# android dev with hardware device, test app dosent run

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Went on a 2 week vacation, forgot something trivial I think.

Im using eclipse for android development on ubuntu. Steps Ive taken :

Ive got adb running, and the device is properly detected. I have done kill-server and start-server numerous times.

I do have unknown sources and USB debugging checked on the device.

I start a new project (file -> new -> android project) and create the most basic android app. I dont modify any of the code. Target = Android 2.2. API = 8.

I choose Run -> run (Ctrl F11). The phone screen does not change. I expected a 'hello world' type message (thats created by the default code). I check the app drawer (is that what were calling that place with all the apps?) It is not in there.

I project -> clean, and stop / restart the server and try again with the same results.

There is nothing in logcat and only a (ignorable?) problem "Attribute minSdkVersion (15) is higher than the project target API level (8)    AndroidManifest.xml /test_july10    line 1  Android ADT Problem"

Please help me from getting more gray hair.

Comment: restarted eclipse, runs fine now. wtf.

Answer (score 1):

Open your Run Configurations (You can right click on project name). Choose the Target tab and select "Always prompt to pick device". Click Apply.

Now try to run your app again. It should bring up a dialog box of available devices. Does your device show. If so choose it and run.

Open DDMS tab (Eclipse Perspective). Make sure your device shows in the list of devices, select it and click the LogCat tab below. Observe any Log messages, or add some to your code.